# 500 internal server error using angular js in laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5, chat

What could be the reason of the following 2 errors in my browser's console.

[image: Errors in console.]

[image]

chat-rooms.js :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('chatApp')

.controller('ChatRoomsCtrl',function($scope,chatRoom,$location){

var chatRoomsLoaded = function(chatRooms){
    $scope.chatRooms = chatRooms;
}
var handleErrors = function(response){
    console.error(response);
}

$scope.selectchatRoom + function(chatRoom){
    $location.path('/#/chat-room/'+ chatRoom.id);
}

$scope.createchatRoom + function(chatRoom){
    chatRoom.create(chatRoom).then($scope.selectchatRoom);
}

chatRoom.getall()
.then(chatRoomsLoaded)
.catch(handleErrors);

});
```

If you need any other file just tell me.

Comment: What's making the Ajax request?

Comment: Then I don't think we can help you. You're making a call to /API/chat-rooms, I would suggest you make sure that endpoint is behaving properly. The code you provided isn't at all related to the problem, a 500 error is an internal server error so it's an error in your back end code.

Comment: @Wade This might helps: http://laravel.io/bin/QN3kx

Comment: That's just a service for making http requests. Is that endpoint working properly? As I've stated before, a 500 error is an internal server error so it has absolutely nothing to do with any JavaScript you write

Comment: Can you paste the service calls which can seen in the DevTools -> Network tab (under XHR) ?

Comment: @DavidR ya sure ,do i give the pic or the code of the files the xhr tab showing?

Comment: @DavidR BTW, its showing 2 files: chat-rooms.html and chat-rooms

Comment: @YaShChaudhary Can you please update your post with those images?

Comment: As @Wade pointed out earlier, Did you check your service is working properly at http://localhost:9090/api/chat-rooms using any rest client?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118781/discussion-between-david-r-and-yash-chaudhary).